# Parsing online XML file into a database with sax using Android

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, xml-parsing, saxparser

I'm currently trying to parse the XML file found on [BNR official site](http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml) using a SAX parser I wrote myself, and getting back the results into a List. The list is meant to be stored into a SQLite database for further use in my application.

The problem is that when I run my app, nothing gets inserted into the database.
Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
package com.example.myapp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;


public class myXMLReader
{
  String urlM;
  DbHandler db;

public void setDatabase (DbHandler db)
{
    this.db=db;
}

   public myXMLReader(){} 


   public List<Record> obtainCurrencyList() throws ParserConfigurationException, 
                                               SAXException, 
                                               IOException
  {
  SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  SAXParser parser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();

  XMLReader xmlReader = parser.getXMLReader();
  XMLHandler currHandler = new XMLHandler();
  currHandler.setDatabase(db);
  ((org.xml.sax.XMLReader) xmlReader).setContentHandler( currHandler);

  URL url = new URL( urlM);
  ((org.xml.sax.XMLReader) xmlReader).parse(new InputSource( url.openStream()));

  return currHandler.getRecList();        
 }
 }
```

Here, the XMLHandler is a class I wrote myself, code is below:

```
  package com.example.myapp;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
  import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
  import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

  public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler{

List<Record> recList = new ArrayList<Record>();
DbHandler db;
String data;
String rate;
String moneda;
String multi;
boolean brate;

public void setDatabase (DbHandler db)
{
    this.db=db;
}


public void startElement( String theNamespaceURI, 
        String theLocalName,
        String theQName, 
        Attributes theAtts) throws SAXException 
        { 


    if  (theLocalName.equals("Cube"))

    {
        data = theAtts.getValue("date");
    }

    //if (data.equals(db.getLastRecord().data)==false)
    {

        if(theLocalName.equals("Rate"))
        {
            moneda = theAtts.getValue("currency");
            multi = theAtts.getValue("multiplier");
            if (multi==null) multi="1";
            //rate = new String();
            brate=true;

        }

    }
        }


  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws 
  SAXException {
    //if (data.equals(db.getLastRecord().data)==false)
    {
        if (localName.equals("Rate"))
            recList.add(new Record( moneda, multi, rate, data));
    }
};


public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException 
{
    if (data.equals(db.getLastRecord().data)==false)
    {
        if (brate)
        {   
            rate = new String(ch,start,length);
            brate = false;
        }
    }
};



List<Record> getRecList()
{
    return recList;
} 
  }
```

Okay, the functions related to the database are contained here, in th DbHandler class:

```
package com.example.myapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHandler
{
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private static Context mCtx;
// All Static variables
// Database Version
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CursBNR";

// Contacts table name
public static final String TODAY = "CursCurent";

// Contacts Table Columns names
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_MONEDA = "Moneda";
public static final String KEY_MULTI = "Multi";
public static final String KEY_RATA = "Rata";
public static final String KEY_DATA = "Data";


public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(mCtx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
String CREATE_TODAY = "CREATE TABLE " + TODAY + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
 AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_MONEDA + " TEXT,"+ KEY_MULTI + " TEXT,"+ KEY_RATA + " TEXT," + 
KEY_DATA + " TEXT" + ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TODAY);
        ;
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TODAY);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**init context, open and close database*/

public DbHandler initcontext(Context ctx) {
    mCtx = ctx;
    return this;
}

public DbHandler open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}




/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addRecord(String MONEDA, String MULTI, String RATA, String DATA) {
    try{
        mDb.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+TODAY+"
('"+KEY_MONEDA+"','"+KEY_MULTI+"','"+KEY_RATA+"','"+KEY_DATA+"') VALUES('"+MONEDA+"', 
'"+MULTI+"', '"+RATA+"', '"+DATA+"');");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Updating single contact
public void updateRecord(String MONEDA, String MULTI, String RATA, String DATA) 
{
    try{
        mDb.execSQL("UPDATE "+TODAY+" SET "+KEY_MONEDA+"='"+MONEDA+"', 
"+KEY_MULTI+"='"+MULTI+"', "+
                KEY_RATA+"='"+RATA+"',"+KEY_DATA+"='"+DATA+"' 
WHERE "+KEY_MONEDA+"='"+MONEDA+"';");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}  


/** 
 * DELETE all students
 */
public void dropAllRecords(){
    try{
        mDb.delete(TODAY, null, null);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }   
}

public void deleteRecords (int ID)
{
    try
    {
        mDb.execSQL("DELETE * FROM"+TODAY+" WHERE "+KEY_ID+"='"+ID+"'");
    }
    catch (SQLException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Record getLastRecord(){

    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+TODAY+" WHERE "+KEY_ID+"=(SELECT 
MAX("+KEY_ID+") FROM "+TODAY+");";
    Cursor cursor = null;
    Record record = new Record();

    try{

        cursor = this.mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        record.setID(cursor.getString(0));
        record.setMoneda(cursor.getString(1));
        record.setMulti(cursor.getString(2));
        record.setRata(cursor.getString(3));
        record.setData(cursor.getString(4));    
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

        //close cursor avoiding memory leaks
    if(!cursor.isClosed())
        cursor.close();

    return record;

}

public int getreccount(){
    //allocate memory
    String query = "SELECT COUNT("+KEY_MONEDA+") FROM "+TODAY;
    int result = 0;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    //fetch result
    try{
        cursor = this.mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getInt(0);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        cursor.close();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //close cursor avoiding memory leaks
    if(!cursor.isClosed())
        cursor.close();

    return result;
}
```

At first it seemed to work until i put the condition:  if (data.equals(db.getLastRecord().data)==false)   , whick is meant to check whether the last recorded item has the same date or not as the items in the xml. If not the, they are supposed to be inserted into the database, which i did via this coding:

NOTE: this is taken from my ProjectActivity.java, a small part of the OnClick() function.

```
myXMLReader XML= new myXMLReader();
XML.setDatabase(dbHandler);
XML.urlM="http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml";


    //create database if necessary, update database

    try
    {
        List <Record> reclist = XML.obtainCurrencyList();


        if (reclist.isEmpty()==false)
        {
            //database gets updated

            for (int i=0; i<reclist.size(); i++)
            {
                dbHandler.addRecord(reclist.get(i).moneda, 
reclist.get(i).multi, reclist.get(i).rata, reclist.get(i).data);    

            }
        } 


    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.i("Exceptie", "Exceptie");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I checked that all variables have been properly set via the Eclipse debugging interface, and the values i got seemed to be right. I have a have a feeling that the getLastRecord() function might have an incorrect behavior if ran on a database with an empty table, but I can't figure out why. As you can see in the code, I already tried commenting the condition but still nothing gets returned into the database.

Any suggestions you might have are highly appreciated, thank you for taking your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be reading this wrong but it looks like you are parsing the XML and then inserting the results BUT you are trying to read "last record inserted" from the db whilst still parsing the XML (ie. before you've inserted anything).

Try keeping a copy of/pointer to the last Record added to `reclist` and use `if(lastRec !=null && data.equals(lastRec.data))`.